# How to dynamically send particular video url from fragment to other activity onclick

Tags: android

I loaded three videos dynamically in a Fragment using list view and managed to send the video URL onclick to other activity where the video is played but the issue here is no matter which video I click the URL of only the first video URL gets passed.

Code -

```
import static ga.asfanulla.openvid2.Constants.FIRST_COLUMN;

public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String JSONUrl = "http://codetest.000webhostapp.com/samplvid/data.php?cat-1";
    private final String TAG_VIDEOS = "cat1";
    private final String TAG_URL = "video_url";
    private final String TAG_TITLE = "video_title";

    private List<String> videoTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> videoURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;

    String name="";
    String VidUrl="";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false); 
        String url = JSONUrl;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON2(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }); 
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON2(String response){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_VIDEOS);

            ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

            list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i=0; i<result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(i);
                name = notice.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                VidUrl = notice.getString(TAG_URL);

                HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, name);
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, VidUrl);
                list.add(temp);
            }

            ListViewAdapters adapter = new ListViewAdapters(getActivity(), list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    int pos=position+1;
                   // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), Integer.toString(pos)+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("videoUrl", VidUrl);
                    intent.putExtra("videoTitle", FIRST_COLUMN);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } 
            }); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you define `VidUrl` ?

Comment: @F43nd1r it is loaded from db and put in a array and displayed using listview adapter

Comment: you need to get data using position from `array or list` which is being used as data source

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i tried that but getposition() Seems to be not working in fragment

Comment: refer my previous comment and hint `intent.putExtra("videoUrl", yourArray[position]);`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh i am getting a error - "Array type expected"  i think this is because it is a ArrayList `list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` please help, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue: you are not putting data in `HashMap` , no `VidUrl` in map

```
HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, name);
list.add(temp)
```

so do

```
JSONObject notice = result.getJSONObject(i);
name = notice.getString(TAG_TITLE);
VidUrl = notice.getString(TAG_URL);
// no VidUrl in hashmap so do
HashMap<String, String> temp= new HashMap<String, String>();
temp.put(name,VidUrl);
list.add(temp);
```

later fetch the `HashMap` and then fetch the value

```
Map.Entry<String,String> entry=list.get(position).entrySet().iterator().next();
//Fetch hashmap object using position ^^^^^^^^^^
// entryset will return list of all entries as Map.Entry
// fetch first entry using iterator().next()
// where via Entry we can access both key and value directly

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoActivity.class);
// i assume your value is the url and key is the title
intent.putExtra("videoUrl", entry.getValue());
intent.putExtra("videoTitle", entry.getKey());
startActivity(intent);
```

Note : you can create your own customize adapter using Your own POJO class

Comment: please could you expain what is `entry.getValue()` and `entry.getKey()` Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete code here is the complete code - https://pastebin.com/5AW0Q3y8

Comment: Oh totally forgot that Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding